# How to change the value of request parameter in Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, input, codeigniter-3

I read the documentation about Input class https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html

I want to change the value of specific parameter using the input class but I can't find it on documentation.

old codes:

```
$_GET['name'] = trim($variable);
```

Change to:

```
$this->input->get('name') = trim($variable);
or
$this->input->name = trim($variable);
```

But it's not working.
how to change the value of parameter using XSS filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You've got it turned around. You don't *set* `$this->input` - as the name suggests, it's `input`, and you **get** it

```
$variable = trim($this->input->get('name'));
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html

and **set** the `output`

```
$this->output->set_output( $variable );
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html